# How to detect Bluetooth device type on C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin

I'm working on app in Xamarin(C# .NET platform) and wondered if I can check the Bluetooth device type (headset, speaker, car audio, etc.) and prevent the device from connecting to one of those types.
for example: discovering all the Bluetooth devices around and allowing the device only to connect to an headset or only previewing the headset devices around.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No.  Why should an app be able to prevent a user from connecting their device to a certain kind of accessory?  What purpose would that serve?

Comment: Just a project I’m working on that I want to show only the relevant Bluetooth connections for a certain activity

Comment: We could get the device for it's bluetooth type instead of device type like headset, speaker, car audio, etc. . https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice#DEVICE_TYPE_CLASSIC